# How do I add hyperlink into each row in dynamic table?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, html-table

```
serialID(AI)|locations | telephone | address
---------------------------------------------
1           | A       
2           | B
3           | C
4           | D

users table
userID | location choosen
-------------------------
1      | A
2      | B
3      | B
```

How do I add hyperlink into each row in dynamic table?

For example(this is a dynamic table) it will change.. depends on the user's favourable.

```
location | address | telephone | user's favourable
B        |  -      | -         |  2
A        |  -      | -         |  1
C        |  -      | -         |  0
D        |   -     | -         |  0
```

So if I hover my mouse to row A, I can go to another php page and display the necessary details example like which users choosen location A. Is there any way to do it? Please help.

This is the create table codes ->

```
<?php
include mysqli.connect.php";

   $retrieveLocation = SELECT l.locations, l.telephone, l.address, COUNT (u.userID) as userID
    FROM location AS l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS u on l.locations = u.location_chosen
    GROUP BY l.locations
    ORDER BY userID DESC;

   $result = $mysqli->query($retrieveLocation);

      while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      { 
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['locations']}</td><td>{$row['telephone']}</td><td>{$row['addression']}</td><td>{$row['userID']}</td></tr>";
      }
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the existing code that creates the table?

Comment: You **are** talking about HTML tables, right?

Comment: @screamout, can we see the PHP code that actually creates the table?  That is what your question is really about.  Also, some more detail about what you want the link to be would be helpful.

Comment: @dan1111 I've edited the post alrdy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to generate the table in html + php:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Location</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Telephone</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach($query as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td><a href="your_url_page_here.php"><?php echo $row["location"]; ?></a></td>
<td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["telephone"]; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```